# Trigger intent without input context

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a intent in dialogflow. I assigned input context to it. So now the intent is only getting trigger when context is there. But i need it to get triggered when context is there and when there is no context, intent should get triggered by just by matching utterance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right approach for handling direct and contextual questions in dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57782957/what-is-the-right-approach-for-handling-direct-and-contextual-questions-in-dialo)

Answer (score 1):

As of right now there is no way to do this with a single intent. Due to the context it will only trigger that intent with an utterance when the context is available. The only way can trigger an intent with context and one without is by creating another intent which does the same thing and has the same utterances, but has no context.

Comment: Given a user input, will the intent with the active context as input context have higher priority? Or will it have the priority as the intent with no context?

Comment: Active contexts will always have higher priority. So if intent A and B both have an utterance "Foo" as a trigger, the intent with the active context will have a higher priority.